# how to use sql query in Laravel query

Tags: laravel-8

SELECT
COUNT(*)
FROM
(
SELECT
tbl_order.order_id
FROM
`tbl_order`
where delete_status=1
group by patient_id,event_no

```
) AS DerivedTableAlias
```

I want this sql in laravel

Answer (score 0):

Try out this query builder query:

```
/DB::table('tbl_order')
->select('patient_id','event_no')
->selectRaw('COUNT(tbl_order.order_id) AS count')
->where('delete_status', 1)
->groupBy('patient_id','event_no')
->get();
```